# Accessing name of the element from a list of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of the dataframes as follows:

```
dept = [Phy,Chem,Bio,Maths,Social]
```

Each of the dataframes have huge amount of data. I need to access the name of these dataframes from the list for further use in looping. I tried this code for example:

```
str(dept[0])
```

But this is giving me the contents of the dataframe 'Phy'. Where as I need just to print 'Phy'.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by the _name_ of a DataFrame. Could you please clarify what it means in your above example? Is it the strings `Phy`, `Chem`, etc. or something else?

Comment: `dept = ['Phy', 'Chem', 'Bio', 'Maths', 'Social']` the list should like this right?

Comment: I have created dataframes from excel using pandas and saved in the above shown names as Phy, Chem, etc. I need to print those names but not the contents in those. @user1953384

Comment: @Huy Your list is showing the strings, while mine is a list of dataframe

Comment: I think you should load your excels by `d = {"Phy":pd.read_excel("path_to_phy_file"), "Chem":pd.read_excel("path_to_chem_file")...}`. Then you can easily reference the name and the dataframe associated with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What follows only makes sense if you do not have the control in the first place on how the dataframes are created (cf. the last section of the answer for a common-sense suggestion).

---

What about mapping objects to their [identity](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/id) using the [globals()](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/globals/) (or [locals()](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/locals/)) function? Thus, let's first define `get_name_of`, a custom function to do this job

```
def get_name_of(o):
    o_id = id(o)
    for objname, obj in globals().items():
        obj_id = id(obj)
        if obj_id == o_id:
            return objname
```

And then use it as follows

```
>>> get_name_of(dept[0])
'Phy'
```

---

That being shown, having to do such thing may be a signal that your code should be somehow "redesigned". If you have the control in the first place on how/when/where the dataframes are created, the best approach is to directly store them in a dictionary with their name. I.e. doing

```
your_dict = {}
# ...
your_dict['Chem'] = pd.DataFrame(...)

# and so on...
```

Comment: Any question @VPN ?

Comment: Yes, I have a question. Why would one prefer this messy id lookup over just storing a dict of dataFrames indexed by a string representing the subject name?

Comment: @cs95 You right. This would of course be better. But the OP may not have the control in the first place on where/how/when the variables are declared. But yes you are right.

Comment: Consider mentioning this in your answer, I'd be happy to upvote it